208V/120V: What phase is my electric panel? 240V Circuit for Electric Hot-water Heater
I live in a mountain ski resort town - well it is a city. I confirmed with our utility company's engineering office that our whole city is supplied by three phase power. Clearly my electric panel has two wires coming in: 208/120V. What would you call my power in my panel? Single phase, double phase or three phase?
I am asking because I am about to hire an electrician to install a 240V/35A circuit to run a new hot water heater. However, because of where I live, I need to make certain I understand what the electrician is doing. The last one I had in last week was lost when he discovered my two hot lines were 208V and 120V. He was expecting them to be 120V each and 240V combined. In fact, it is what prompted me to phone the engineer at the utility.
I am researching electric hot water heaters with tanks for purchase to install in my new office space. Home Depot has a few 50-55gal options that I am considering. I wanted to select one that had leak detection and auto shutoff. However, I believe due to the electronic intricacies of these features, I am not able to have it installed with my 208V/120V supply. I noticed in the online manual it only indicated 240V with 25A or 30A circuits in the Branch Circuit diagram.
Would anyone know if this could be because of the "smart" features and wifi capability? I ask because there is another model that does not have the leak detection and auto shutoff. Its manual has a more elaborate Branch Circuit Diagram that does include more voltage/amperage options besides 240V. In the case of 208V, you would simply raise the amperage on the circuit from 30A to 35A to achieve the 5500W power output on the elements. This model also has an LED diagnostic indicator for the elements. Does it make sense to you more seasoned folks that even with an LED diagnostic element indicator, the less "smart" (i.e. no wifi capability) model can run on 208V and 35A? I phoned Rheem today and asked if the hot water heaters at Home Depot could run on 208V and he said, "Yes, just increase the amperage of the circuit." However, it wasn't until after I hung up that I realized the differences in the manuals of the two different models.
What do you folks think? And again, is a 208/120V panel single, double or three phase?

What specific models are you considering?

Please break your wall of text into sensible paragraphs. It's hard on my eyes.


However, I believe due to the electronic intricacies of these features, I am not able to have it installed with my 208V/120V supply. I noticed in the online manual it only indicated 240V with 25A or 30A circuits in the Branch Circuit diagram.

In general, modern electronics can handle a pretty wide range of supply voltage. Most devices that are designed to operate on 240V can accept 208V just fine. It certainly is possible for a device to specifically require 240V, though, so follow the instructions for the specific unit.

In the case of 208V, you would simply raise the amperage on the circuit from 30A to 35A to achieve the 5500W power output on the elements.

Plain old resistive elements will produce their full rated 240V wattage only if fed 240V. They're just resistors, subject to Ohm's law. A 5500W element will draw 23A at 240V, but it will draw only 20A at 208V and produce only 4100W. It'll still work, but it will be slower to heat/recover.
Heat-pump based units (being motor loads instead of resistors) may be different.

Thank you for your reply.  P = IV or E = IV and therefore what you have answered seems very logical to me.  However, do you have any thoughts as to why the Branch Circuit Table in the hot water heater's manual has this listed:

Varying amperage and wire gauge size depending one the voltage?  They had different voltages:  120V, 208V, 240V, 277V, 480V

Cutting and pasting isn't too clear, could you link to the page?

chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/58/58a3e920-691c-464f-9a69-cb7a431dbad4.pdf

Pages 8 & 9 of that document.  My concern is will I get enough power to  produce enough hot water to mix to about 103F at 5GPM flow rate.  If the hot water heater is able to run 208V at 26A, then I would get 5500W.  What dictates the amperage?

The water heater will be available with a variety of different element models - a 5.5kW 208V element, 5.5kW 240V, maybe some options at 277 and 480V. The physical construction is different between the different element sizes and voltages. All the manufacturer can do is manufacture an element of X ohms that can safely dissipate Y watts.

The words for what you have are network service
In densely built areas, utilities often use a secondary network service system that allows them to put all the transformers in an area effectively in parallel.  This improves the ability to supply high capacity services and also provides a degree of redundant backup in case a single transformer has trouble.
However, this trick only works with three-phase service, and is normally done with a three-phase wye (Y) service configuration.  That way, when a nominally split-phase load, like a house, needs to be hooked up to a network distribution system, the utility can grab any two phase wires and the neutral from the secondary network and run it to you just as if it was a split-phase service.
This does tend to trip up electricians who don't see it much, either because they work mostly on single-family homes with normal split-phase service or because they work mostly on commercial and industrial buildings that have three-phase service.

Thank you for your reply.  So in your opinion, which type of wire should an electrician be purchasing for this situation?  8-2 for a 35A circuit with a 2-pole breaker is correct I assume because there are only two wires coming into the panel.  Then the electrician only needs three wires total:  2 load lines and one ground . . .  yes?  I hate that I know just enough to get myself into trouble and not enough to get myself out.  Uhg.  I hate even more that I have to constantly watch over every aspect of this remodel or the workers louse it all up.  Uhg.

Should the local electricians not know about this?  I assume the OP did not fly an electrician in from another part of the state.

@HandyJen -- 8/2 is correct for a 35A, line-to-line only circuit.   Your heater may not make the full 5500W at 208V though (it depends on if the heater is fitted with 208V specific elements or is left with the "stock" 240V elements)

TL;DR 208V vs. 240V = no big deal
US residential electric service is typically supplied as 240V with a center tap. So 240V between the ends and 120V between each end and the middle, with the middle being neutral (and bonded to ground).
With 208V it is more complicated. There are three phases and a neutral in between. The voltage is 208V between any pair of phases and 120V between each phase and neutral. This turns out to be a more efficient way of transmitting large amounts of power, so it is commonly used in apartment buildings, large office buildings, industrial buildings and similar installations. It has the advantage that it can provide 3-phase power for large equipment.
In order to not have to have, for example, different ovens and clothes dryers and water heaters for apartment buildings (mostly 208V) and single-family homes (mostly 240V), manufacturers generally design appliances to handle the entire range from 208V to 240V, or commonly as much as 200V to 250V. Conveniently, just as "regular" 120V service (for all your residential stuff except big appliances) was actually 110V and then 115V at various times over the past several decades, 240V was 220V and then 230V. So appliances already were designed to handle a range of 220V to 240V and 208V isn't that much lower than 220V.
Using one typical water heater from Home Depot, the Rheem 50 Gallon 4500W, the installation instructions actually lists specific breaker sizes for 208V vs. 240V vs. 277V vs. 480V. Even more interesting, they have a single phase wiring table and a 3 phase wiring table. They're the same table, except the 3 phase wiring table leaves out the 120V column and the smallest models. Why? Because a water heater connected with two wires of single phase (240V) is exactly the same as a water heater connected with two out of three wires of 3 phase (usually 208V), except for an adjustment based on the voltage.

At the source of power it is 3 phase, but when you have only two of those legs your appliances only see single phase.
Looks like a straight resistive tank, so at 240v 5500w what you have is a +/- 10.4 ohm element. So when you reduce voltage to 208v
at 10.5 ohm you get 19.8A.
So 19.8A times 125% for constant current you get 25A breaker, so #10 AWG.
Most inspectors let you oversize water heater to 30A, but 25A is a standard breaker size in NEC 240.6.

Since you're going to this much trouble to figure things out, it makes sense to understand the critical pieces.  The power source, the circuit breaker, the wire size, the water heating elements and the water heater connection possibilities (if any).

Power Source: you have two "hot" wires and a neutral.  So that's 3 wires in total. You measure respectively 120vac and 208vac between the two hot wires and the neutral.  One thing you could do to satisfy curiosity is to measure the AC voltage between the two hot wires.  This will allow you to figure out the phases.  If the wiring comes from a WYE 3-phase transformer configuration, which would be common in the type of development you describe, then you would might measure 120v.  I've not tried to figure out what their practices are that makes the neutral setup shown in this diagram likely.
Circuit Breaker:  The circuit breaker needs to support the steady-state load of the heating elements as well as any current surges that happen when a cold heating element is first energized. Using typical design criteria it would be rated at 30% above the steady-state load (e.g 5500 Watts divided by volts).  The Rheem data sheets match this rating for both 208v and 240v with 5500 watt heaters.  I didn't see how one might specify a water heater for one voltage or another and I'm not sure one should trust the voltages listed at 208v or at 240v - as the industry seems to tend toward "one size fits all".  Perhaps others will have better information on this.
Wire size:  goes along with the circuit breaker size.
Water heater elements:  You can find more electric water heater elements rated at 5500W at 240v than you can find them rated at 5500W and 208V.  And, the industry suggests that there are water heaters that work on either one.
What does that mean?  A 5500W heater at 240v will dissipate 4130 watts at 208v.  Heating 50 gallons of water from 50 deg F to 150 deg F will take 2.22 hours at 240v and 2.96 hours at 208v.  This extreme should be unusual and the 45-minute difference likely not noticeable at that.
Water heater connection possibilities:  (or heating element choices).  I wasn't able to find compelling evidence.
I think this means that manassehkatz-moving-2-codidact makes a good point.

